# What does message "chassis marginal" mean from VMware ESXi 4.1 SNMP trap on a Dell PowerEdge R710 server?

Tags: vmware-esxi, snmp, dell-poweredge

Wanted to post this here in case anyone else has this issue.
We have a Dell PowerEdge R710 running VMWare ESXi 4.1, we got an SNMP trap message 
via Nagios monitoring:

SERVICE CHECK: theServerName;SnmpTrap;2;chassis marginal Type: chassis Status: marginal Name: 'VMware Rollup Health State' value: 0 233:2:10:09.44

We found a post on VMware Communities about it:

VMware Communities post about SNMP message: http://communities.vmware.com/thread/345217

```
vmwESXEnvHardwareEvent
[1] vmwSubsystemType.2 (Integer): chassis
[2] vmwHardwareStatus.2 (Integer): marginal
[3] vmwEventDescription.2 (DisplayString): Type: chassis Status: marginal Name: 'VMwareRollup Health State' value: 0 
[4] vmwEnvHardwareTime.2 (Time Ticks): 350 days 09:16:01
[5] snmpTrapEnterprise.0 (Object ID): vmwESX
```

Then the error did go away after a bit (another SNMP trap received):

```
SERVICE ALERT: theServerNameSnmpTrap;CRITICAL;SOFT;1;chassis normal Type: chassis Status: normal Name: 'VMware Rollup Health State' value: 0 233:9:46:00.04
```

What does "chassis marginal" mean in this case?

Answer (score 0):

In our case it was the battery in the Perc h700. It was equivalent to "Cache Battery 0 in controller 0 is Charging (Ready) [probably harmless]." message going from an SNMP get.

The cache battery charges from time to time, and as long as that charging completes within a few hours everything is OK.